# Optaplanner input format for mixed vehicles, pick-up&delivery, etc

Tags: input, optaplanner, mixed

I am using Optaplanner to work on some VRP cases. I have played with some simple cases, but have some more complex ones, too.

I can't find example .vrp or .xml inputs to model those cases. Can anyone propose some, or should I define the format and code the import myself?

The main issues right now are:

- non-homogenous fleet; I have many different vehicles available, with different capacities, sizes and even possible different available time windows and starting locations. What input format supports that?
- several O/D matrices; when having different vehicle types, e.g. vans and trucks, the travel times and distances also differ - one should use different O/D matrices. How to tackle that?
- pick-up&delivery; many cases need to handle pick-up and delivery. In simplest cases there are several depots with different cargo stored, in more complex it is about shuttle transport.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: 1) and 2) relatively straigthforward if you just edit Vehicle.java accordingly. 3) however, when pickups and deliveries are mixed in the same route, it is [a different beast](https://github.com/ge0ffrey/optaplanner-mixedvrp-experiment).

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I was able to do 1) pretty simple, I haven't gotten into 2) yet, will try your suggestion for 3) also.

Comment: Just one more thing about the solution - I don't like the XML saved file too much, so I have tried to write my own txt exporter - I am just not sure where to call it from... How to enable the Export button and trigger it from there? Thank you!

Comment: Ah, found the Export functionality - I have followed the model of the TspExporter and created VehicleRoutingExporter.